# Replacing content of a div with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this div

```
<div class="right-content"> </div>
```

in which I load all the data I want to show via AJAX.
I have loaded some html in it which has a link like

```
<%= link_to job_applicants_path(j.id), :class => "applicants-link" do %>
    <span class="badge"><%= cantSolic (j.id) %></span>
<% end %>
```

And when I click on that link, I'd like to remove the previous content of the right-content div and load the new html from job_applicants' view, but it's loading it like a new page. How can I do this?
This is the js I'm using:

```
$(".applicants-link").click(function(){
    var link = $(this);
    var path = link.attr("href");
    if (path != null){
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            async: true,
            success: function(result){
                $(".right-content").html(result);
            },
            error: function(result){
                $(".right-content").html ("<h4>No se ha podido cargar la información solicitada. Intentelo más tarde.</h4>")
            }
        })
    return false;
    } 
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has a way to handle this without writing on click functions and $ajax calls. Change your link so that rails knows that you want to send an ajax request by adding `:remote => true`:

```
<%= link_to job_applicants_path(j.id), :class => "applicants-link", :remote => true do %>
<span class="badge"><%= cantSolic (j.id) %></span>
```

Then in your controller (I am assuming job_applicants_path is routed to a "show" action in your controller) respond to the ajax request and do anything specific to an ajax request:

```
def show
  #your logic for all requests types here
  @some_variable = "abc123"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.js { #do any ajax specific stuff here }
  end
end
```

Rails will then send the contents of file `show.js.erb` to be executed as JS, so you can put something like this in it:

```
$(".right-content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'name_of_your_partial_to_render', locals: { some_variable: @some_variable}))%>")
```

Answer (score 0):

- 1 , the data that is coming from another page , is getting loaded into that `<div class="right-content">` which you are calling it as 
  'Entire Page'.
- 2 , you can place a `<div>` giving it an id on that page(to be fetched) , then make a simple ajax request to load the content.

  $('#currentdiv').load('page.asp #div_to_load');

It will load the content of `#div_to_load` from another page into `#currentdiv` of your current page.